# php, perl, question. what does this mean: " $variable -> do some sort of function "

Tags: php, perl, operator-keyword

I have seen this (example: **$variable -> define something**) in both perl and php but I never really used it before. What is the purpose of this operator -> Does it assign a value or pass a param?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**PHP**

It's used in OOP it can be a method(But then there would ofcourse be () at the end) or a property of a class.
I don't know perl so i cannot tell you what it is there but for php :
Some example that hopefully clarify something :

We can make a object of a class in php like this :

```
$object = new MyClass();
```

Now if we have a method in that called peer you would call it like this :

```
$object -> getInstance();
```

And if we have a property in that same class called spoon you would echo it like this :

```
echo $object -> instance;
```

This works but you could also create a getter method in your class
And a little example of a class :

```
class MyClass { 

   // property instance 
   private $instance; 

   protected __construct() 
   { 

   } 
   // getInstance method 
   protected static function getInstance() 
   { 
      return $this -> instance;
   }
}
```

Might want to take a look here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

**Perl**

The arrow operator is mostly used in dereferencing a method or variable from an object or a class name  `$obj->$a` is an example to access variable `$a` from object `$obj`.
It can also be used to call methods instead like : `$obj->$a()`
For more information visit this url : http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator

Comment: So its just a way to access a method in an object? So let me just shoot you a random example:   

    $ccc->define($key=>$value);

Is $ccc in the object or is it passing its value to the object? 
If $Key is bigger or equal to $value, $key gets assigned the value of $ccc?

Do I understand this right?

Comment: it depends on the implementation of the `define` method. but beyond that, your syntax is wrong. the `=>` operator can only be used in array definitions.

Comment: oh sorry the example I gave you is in perl. Its a strange language.

Comment: I added a few examples in php i hope they help

Comment: Great example Mythje. Thanks for the help! I think I got it now!

Answer (score 9):

In Perl, the `->` operator means both dereference and invoke, depending on what is to the right of the operator.  If the rhs is a bracketed subscript `[...]`, `{...}`, or `(...)` is a dereference.  If it is a scalar `$some_name` or a bareword `some_name` it is invoking a method call.

```
my $array_ref = [1, 2, 3];

say $array_ref->[2];  # prints 3
say $$array_ref[2];   # also prints 3

my $hash_ref = {a => 1, b => 2};

say $hash_ref->{b};   # prints 2
say $$hash_ref{b};    # also prints 2

my $code_ref = sub {"[@_]"};

say $code_ref->('hello');  # prints "[hello]"
say &$code_ref('hello');   # also prints  "[hello]"

my $object = Some::Package->new();

$object->some_method(...);  # calls 'some_method' on $object

my $method = 'foo';

$object->$method(...);   # calls the 'foo' method on $object

$object->$code_ref(...);  # same as $code_ref->($object, ...)
```

I personally prefer to use the doubled sigil form of dereferencing for arrays and hashes, and use the `->` only for calling code references and for calling methods.

Answer (score 3):

As for perl, the `->` operator may mean:

- dereferencing array, hash, or subrouting reference, see [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- method call, see [perdoc perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html).

Oh and maybe I've forgotten something.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Ahhh I really do not like Perl.